# Automate data in one column of an access table based on another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm making a library table that has a list of books and their authors. I then have this code that generates a hash code to give it a position in my library.

```
Public Function GenerateHash(word As String, arraySize As Integer) As BigInteger
    Dim wordBytes() As Byte
    wordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(word)

    Dim array() As BigInteger
    ReDim array(0 To arraySize - 1)

    Dim hash As BigInteger
    hash = 5381
    For i = 0 To UBound(wordBytes)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + wordBytes(i)
    Next i

    Dim index As Integer
    index = Math.Abs(CDec(hash Mod arraySize))
    array(index) = hash

    GenerateHash = index
End Function
```

I'm mainly not sure where to call this function and then how to copy it into each row referencing that rows book title and author column.
(I probably need to edit it to take in two cells of information and handle it as one string)

I tried asking chatGPT but it just said to "Click on the Text Box control in the Controls section of the Ribbon." and I couldn't find it so assumed it didn't know.

Comment: ok, I've edited the code. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column (field) to your table with the datatype 'Calculated'. If you do this the Expression-Builder will pop up. If it does not, select your field and navigate to the field properties. On the row 'Expression' you can call your function manually or by using the Expression-Builder (click on the three dots at the end of the line).

Comment: can this be used to call a function? if so, how?